# "Invalid parameter number" in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm doing a prepared statement in PDO. I'm getting the error written below and I don't know where's my mistake.

> Error!: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Code:

```
$qA=array();
$lastName=$_POST['cours'];

if(trim($_POST["nomActivity"]) != ""){
  $nomActivity= filter_var($_POST['nomActivity'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $qA[] = "a.title = :title";
}
if(trim($_POST["nPlace"]) != ""){
  $nPlace= filter_var($_POST['nPlace'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
  $qA[] = "a.nPlace = :nPlaceA";
} 
if(isset($_POST['date'])){
  $date = $_POST['date'];
  $qA[] = "a.date = :date";
}

$stmtA = $con->prepare("UPDATE activity a SET " . implode(", ", $qA) . " where a.title= :lastN");

if(trim($_POST["nomActivity"]) != ""){
  $stmtA->bindParam(":title", $nomActivity);
} 
if(trim($_POST["nPlace"]) != ""){
  $stmtA->bindParam(":nPlaceA", $nPlace);
} 
if(trim($_POST["date"]) != ""){
  $stmtA->bindParam(":date", $date);
}
if(trim($_POST["cours"]) != ""){
  $stmtA->bindParam(":lastN", $lastName);
} 

$stmtA->execute();
```

Comment: You are always using `:lastN` in your query (`where a.title= :lastN`), but you are contitionally binding it.  That means there are cases where it might not be bound.

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: @tadman: as much as I liked Propel in its heyday, Propel is essentially abandoned now. The maintainers gave up with refactoring Propel2 and have not made a [Propel3](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel3) release in two years.

Comment: @halfer I'm always open to updating those recommendations with more current examples. Have any suggestions or favorites?

Comment: @tadman: I wish I did, but while there's [plenty of PHP ORM projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108699), none of them are particularly substantial or current. Doctrine and Eloquent are the only serious/maintained ones I know of. I'd be happy to be corrected on this too!

Comment: ([This looks OK](http://j4mie.github.io/idiormandparis/) but both of the subprojects are declared feature-frozen now, so I don't know what the maintenance status is now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems you miss the proper check for cours

```
  if(trim($_POST["nomActivity"]) != ""){
    $nomActivity= filter_var($_POST['nomActivity'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $qA[] = "a.title = :title";
  }
  if(trim($_POST["nPlace"]) != ""){
    $nPlace= filter_var($_POST['nPlace'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $qA[] = "a.nPlace = :nPlaceA";
  } 
  if(isset($_POST['date'])){
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $qA[] = "a.date = :date";
  }

  // this one
  if(isset($_POST['cours'])){
    $lastName=$_POST['cours'];
  } else {
    $lastName = 'your_default_value';
  }
```

and you have always :lastN to assign

```
  $stmtA->bindParam(":lastN", $lastName);
```

Comment: @PatrickQ  correct  .. answer updated . with a suggestion for default value of not $_POST['cours']

Comment: @scaisEdge, @Patrick Q Is it necessary since `cours` is from a select with option required ?

Comment: @Hiiro   . a value for $lastName is necessary for binding the :lastN  . that is always present .. so or you assign when cours is present or you assign a value by default   ( or you change the where condition)

Comment: There will always be a value for `$lastName` since it come from this `<select required class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" name="cours" id="cours">`. The user is forced to choose a value. I moved out `$lastName` from the condition and the error is gone. Thanks anyway !

Comment: then remember to assign ever the related values in $stmtA->bindParam(":lastN", $lastName);   in your cade you assign this param only of cours is on $_POST ... as is suggested  at the bottom pf my answer  ..